# node.js POST request

Tags: node.js, http

I looked at the api but I couldn't find it.

Where/How should I put data on a POST request on `client.request()` or `client.request("POST" ,...)`?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you should look closer then.

This is straight from the node.js API documentation:

> request_headers is optional.
>   Additional request headers might be
>   added internally by Node. Returns a
>   ClientRequest object.
>
> Do remember to include the
>   Content-Length header if you plan on
>   sending a body. If you plan on
>   streaming the body, perhaps set
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked.
>
> NOTE: the request is not complete.
>   This method only sends the header of
>   the request. One needs to call
>   request.end() to finalize the request
>   and retrieve the response. (This
>   sounds convoluted but it provides a
>   chance for the user to stream a body
>   to the server with **request.write()**.)

`request.write()` is for sending data.

So you do it like this (more or less):

```
var rq = client.request('POST', 'http://example.org/', {'Content-Length': '1024'});
var body = getMe1024BytesOfData();

rq.write(body);
rq.end();
```

*This code is just here to get the concept across. I have NOT tested it in any way.*

Comment: you can also do rq.end(body) if that suits your style better

Comment: True, but I like to keep things with different purposes apart: write() is for output and end() is for ... well ... ending.

Comment: This seems to have changed in v0.3.6. and seems much different [now in v0.4.7](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/http.html#http.request)

Answer (score 1):

For more easier client requests you can use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module. It takes care of all the hard work and has a simple API.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Requestify](http://ranm8.github.io/requestify), a really cool and very simple HTTP client I wrote for nodeJS + it supports caching.

Just do the following for executing a POST request:

```
var requestify = require('requestify');

requestify.post('http://example.com', {
    hello: 'world'
})
.then(function(response) {
    // Get the response body (JSON parsed or jQuery object for XMLs)
    response.getBody();
});
```